# AWS Glue/Athena: Combine many small parquet files for performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, parquet, amazon-athena

I have a use case as follows:

An IoT device is uploading many small files into an AWS S3 input bucket. Upon upload, every single file is processed by an AWS Lambda function to decode the data and write a parquet output file based on the uploaded IoT log file.

The parquet file is written to an output S3 bucket, which serves as my data lake. The output S3 bucket is crawled by AWS Glue and queried via AWS Athena.

The structure of my output S3 bucket is as follows:

```
s3://outputbucket/deviceid/tablename/fileid.parquet
```

Note that I deliberately do not have partitions as this is not possible within my use case.

My challenge is this:

Due to the file-by-file processing, I get a very large number of small parquet files (e.g. millions of 5-100 kb files) in my data lake, reducing Athena's performance.

I would like to deploy a serverless AWS service that will on-demand "concatenate/combine" my small parquet files into larger parquet files in a simple way. The resulting larger parquet files should be compressed etc. For example, a single table folder may contain 1 GB of data across 10K files - and the service/job should "transform" this folder to contain 1 GB of data across 10 files.

At the same time, I wish to ensure that these combined files remain in my output S3 bucket (rather than put them into a separate S3 bucket), as I ideally want the 'combined' data to be queried together with the new incoming data from my existing Lambda functions.

Can this be done via e.g. AWS Glue, AWS Athena or some other solution?

Comment: Just curious what solution you ended up going with? I have a similar problem where I need to batch data in an S3 folder and output to a separate S3 folder.

Comment: We ended up supporting this within our software tools for decoding, enabling users to locally pull data from their S3 input bucket and then output it to an S3 output bucket in concatenated form, with the concatenation logic being specific to our use case (typically resulting in 1 file per day, instead of sometimes e.g. 500 files per day). Not ideal, though, as it requires users to periodically 're-process' their backlog to get it compacted.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I am no aws expert. Usually I fail understanding their docs...
However, maybe S3 selcet could be of interest for you:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/selecting-content-from-objects.html

with this you can select columns from csv, parquet and json files. I would expect it to work also across multiple files. Hope that is of help and good luck to you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS Glue ETL to [repartition](https://medium.com/@vadivel_43566/compact-parquet-files-using-aws-glue-efcfc9a19564) your table, thus compacting files.

Also it might be interesting for you to look into [Delta Lake](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/delta-lake-tables.html), since this provides compaction out of the box

Comment: Thanks! Delta Lake seems like it’s more complex - and as if it may not be possible to run in a server less manner like the rest of my setup? As for the partitioning via ETL, I guess this could eg be run every month. I would, however, prefer that it runs on my parquet data lake bucket directly. A table may eg have 1000 small files before a run and I would like to always combine this to eg 10 files. But how does one ensure that I delete all the smaller files and only retain the combined files? I can see this done with some Python code, but unsure if there is a best practice..

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS Kinesis firehose for sending the data to S3.

as IOT Devices are keep sending the data and it is generating the small files you can configure the AWS Kinesis firehose S3 Buffer Size which is 1MB to 128MB or Buffer Interval to 60 to 900 seconds.

It will also do the partition in S3, you can do that based on the date thus query will much faster in Athena.